# Why is my wordpress site slow and loading taking forever?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website, that is constantly stuck in loading: www.reggeliprofeta.hu also the article page like https://www.reggeliprofeta.hu/index.php/2018/11/06/ahany-haz-annyi-szemelyiseg/ .

I saw that some FB related images were loading forever, so I switched these modules off, yet it still doesn't load in Chrome.

Do you have any idea what might cause this?

many thanks

Comment: Your site is working fine , there is issue of loader , Please remove site loader

Comment: how should I do that in the theme?

Comment: thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: i have paste the answer below, please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the Below code in your current active theme's functions.php file **(at this location /wp-content/themes/magazina)**

```
function hide_loader_after_window_load(){ ?>
  <script>
  $(window).on('load', function() {
   $('.group-loader').css('display','none');
   });
  <script>
<?php 
}

add_action('wp_head','hide_loader_after_window_load');
```

Comment: i've added it. now it loads instantly but it breaks the site - only white background ,logo is missing, on article page only the footer shows. I removed for the interim - does it matter which part of the function.php do I paste it to? thanks again

Comment: At this location /wp-content/themes/magazina/functions.php file , Please add at the end of file . Its shows white screen because there is error with php one and closing tag

Comment: added to the end. you can see what happens now, breaks again.

Comment: Ok leave it , Go to your admin dashboard and install this plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/ , create custom js file and paste this code in it 
 $(window).on('load', function() {
   $('.group-loader').css('display','none');
   });

Comment: Please mark as an answer and do upvote so it helps other developers too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add these css lines from customizer option in wordpress

```
.group-loader {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: the site was working after adding that. .Remove php codes if u have added any. That css will not break your site